# Why didn’t Ego collect the Infinity Stones to make the entire universe like himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

Ego was alone in ALL of the universe for millions of years as he began to learn without being taught by any older being (that’s odd in itself, but not the question I'd like an answer to at this point in time).

Why didn't Ego simply collect all the Infinity Stones, which would then have given him all the power he said he needed to make the universe better?

I understand this is all just comic book stuff, but I think it should all follow some level of logic, unless specifically stated that it defies logic.

Comment: A couple of other notes: I'm not particularly convinced that the average person watching an MCU film knows much about the comics. And, Thanos and Ego (in particular) are quite different in the MCU than in the comics, so expecting their actions in the comics to explain issues you have with their MCU portrayal will likely end in disappointment.

Comment: Reply to RDFozz... I’m not concerned with the comics. Too much material there. And I’m pretty sure I never asked for an explanation about the comic to movie series differences.  I’m just wanting my title question answered if possible. As I wrote to the previous comment post about too many questions in one post. Simply answer me this...Why didn’t Ego collect the stones to gain the power over everything and create the universe filled with only himself as he said he wanted when trying to get Quill to help him. One Celestial couldn’t do it alone, but two...

Comment: I’ve edited the post to focus on what you’re actually asking rather than everything else you’ve put in there. Note to reply to a user you can do the following so they get pinged @NealVan

Comment: “Why didn't Ego simply collect all the Infinity Stones” — simply. Sure. Reeeeeeeeal simple.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two reasons.

1. Ego already had a plan set in motion, and wasn't going to deviate from what he thought was going to work.  Seed all worlds, father a child with the infinity gene, absorb the celestial energy from his child, and spread across every life sustaining world in the universe.  In fact, it was a good plan that almost worked, had he not been killed by the Guardians.  If the plan failed, and he still lived, perhaps he might have considered the infinity stones as an alternative.
2. The infinity stones are known to be dangerous to those who wield them.  Weaker beings are shown to explode when touching the stones.  Most of the characters that use them put them into some kind of container.  Perhaps the stones are still dangerous even to the most powerful Celestials like Ego. Thanos had to wear them in the gauntlet to protect himself so it is not inconceivable that the stones were dangerous to Ego as well.  Ego might have decided not to go after the stones, deeming using them too risky.

Comment: “Thanos had to wear them in the gauntlet to protect himself” — did he? He seemed to handle individual stones just fine when required.

Comment: It's a bit of speculation on my part.  He only handles the stones briefly before popping them into his gauntlet.  Nearly all the other characters that try to use the infinity stones place them in some sort of container (e.g. Ronin).  It would make sense that these containers function in part to protect their uses from the power of the stones.

Comment: Plan 1 is actually kinda terrible if you think about it. It all hinges on whether he can father a child who has Celestial power. After eons of trying, he managed to pull off one, and he couldn't even properly ensure that that child would share his philosophy. If he was simply incapable of fathering such a child, if that child had died of something stupid before he found out about it etc., the "plan" fails big-time.

Answer (score 0):

The Infinity Gems/Stones were scattered across multiple universes, and as far as I know, Ego did not have the power to travel through dimensions.

Comment: Do you have a source for the Infinity Stones being scattered in different universes?  The answer is a bit light on supporting details without that.

Comment: This may be true for the comics, however, it isn't true at all for the MCU which this question is about. (CC @DavidW)